# How to catch an event after all content is loaded when all controllers are initialized inside an ng-repeat in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback, controller, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<!-- Begin page content part of a pageCtrl -->
<div class="container" ng-init="pageInit();">
   <div class="template {{block.type}}" ng-repeat="block in pageBlocks" my-repeat-directive>
     <div ng-controller="templateCtrl" ng-include src="'partials/components/' + block.type + '.html'" ng-init="initTemplate(block);"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Inside my ng-repeat I initialize dynamically some small templates with my **templateCtrl** passing some data from my **pageCtrl** scope.
My goal is to be able to execute some javascript after all the content of my templates is loaded and compiled by Angularjs.

But at the moment I cannot find an "after all is compiled" event to manage some simple callback operations.

I tried directives & on-last-repeat operations on the ng-repeat, i tried scope.$watch, $timeout,  $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded')... but any working behaviours.

any idea, suggestions? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some other attmepts i end up in this solution, that seems to work really fine.

this in the html

```
<div ng-controller="templateCtrl" ng-include src="'partials/components/' + block.type + '.html'" ng-init="initTemplate(block);" template-directive></div>
```

and this in javascript

```
app.directive('templateDirective', function($timeout){
  return {
    restrict: "EA",
    compile: function(element, attributes){
      return {
        post: function(scope, element, attributes, controller, transcludeFn){

          if(scope.$last){
            $timeout(function(){
              //operations in the callback
            }, 250);
          }
        }
      };
    }
  };
});
```

do the experts agree?